# Как включить подсветку синтаксиса android в Android-studio

Tags: android-studio, синтаксис

После каких-то действий у меня отключилась подсветка синтаксиса. Действия я не запомнил.

Как вернуть подсветку назад?

[image: Cабж]

Comment: Но подсветка то работает - ключевые слова выделены синим.

Comment: Android подсветка не работает,там раньше android подсвечивалось фиолетовым,setContentView тоже подсвечивалось и др.

Comment: Проблема возникает только с этим проектом и только с конкретно этим файлом, или со всеми файлами Java? Пришлите, пожалуйста, registered patterns для Java Class и Java Source (Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> File Types), возможно проблема именно там.

Comment: попробуйте руками прописать import com.example.vladimir.myapplication.R; И еще clean и rebuil project тоже

Answer (score 1):

Поробуйте в Settings в поле поиска вбить слово `highlighting` и пройтись по результатам.

Если не поможет то в каталоге пользователя найти папку с настройками и удалить ее, она пересоздастся заново (В моем случае называется `.AndroidStudio1.4`)

Comment: Сделал,не сработало!